# jquery change all value attr for input fields

Tags: jquery, selector, each, attr

This doesn't apply to form fields.

Let's say I have this in html:

```
<input id="something" value="myvalue">
<input id="somethingelse" value="myvalue">
```

And I have javascript that does this:

```
something.value="ME";
somethingelse.value="TOO";
```

And I want to manipulate the DOM so that when we inspect the element "something" it reflects this:

```
<input id="something" value="ME">
```

If I do this in jquery explicitly it works:

```
$("#something").attr("value",something.value.toString());
```

But I need something more generic - I need to change EVERY input item so that it behaves like this.

So I tried:

```
$("input").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("value", this.value.toString());
})
```

But it doesn't change at all.  It leaves it alone.

So I tried this:

```
$("input").each(function () {
$(this).attr("value", "NeverA");
})
```

And it doesn't change it either.

But I tried

```
$("input").each(function () {
    alert(this.value.toString());
})
```

And it is alerting each value - so the selector is good.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, doing toString() on a string is useless.

Comment: You're going to have to describe your problem in a little more depth. It's not exactly clear what you want to do.

Comment: what's type of input fields? Should be text, if you have "number" instead you will see nothing

Comment: Your code works as-is in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7bkcc9Lr/  If I inspect the inputs, I see their values.

Comment: Rick - I don't know how to mark your answer correct or even if I need to but here's my fiddle and it does indeed work.

Comment: Rick,  I can't mark your answer correct but here's a link to my fiddle which when I pasted in your fiddle worked fine.  I don't know what I had wrong but I suspect a misplaced paren or something.  http://jsfiddle.net/t2nrkeyt/  In my prior testing I seemed to need the toString to get it to work as a parm to the Jquery but I took it out and things seem to work as I desire.  The REASON for all of this is that I have an Ajax Generated site and I want it indexed by search engines.  So I'm making an html snapshot and want the values to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick had the proper answer in code - though mine looks correct in the question, the code I had in my jsfiddle must have had some sort of unreported error because it just didn't work.  Pasting in the code from Rick's fiddle worked fine.  Here's my fiddle with the answer and a few more types of input fields.

The answer:

```html
<input id="something" value="myvalue">
<input id="somethingelse" value="SE">
<input id="ANum" type="number" value=99>
<input id="button" type="button" value="OK">

<script>
  something.value = "NEVER";
  button.value = "Not OK";
  ANum.value = 9342;

  $("input").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("value", this.value);
  })
</script>
```

Fiddle for this:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/t2nrkeyt/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a class:

```
$(function(){
$("#Goo").click(function(){
    $(".test").each(function() {
        $(this).val("otherValue");
    });
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtzqggot/

Answer (score 1):

Simple `$("input").attr("value", "NewString")` works for me. You can pass in a function as second parameter to modify the values according to your needs.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqf5crns/)

Comment: @epascarello apparently it wasn't. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: Also not work, using `$('selector').val()` returns the old value.

Answer (score 0):

It can be more simple. Just do it:

```
<div id="parentDivID">
    <input id="something" value="myvalue">
    <input id="somethingelse" value="SE">
    <input id="ANum" type="number" value=99>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="OK">
</div>

<script> 
    $("#parentDivID").find('input').val(''); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the descendants with the selector

```
<div id="parentDivID">
    <input id="something" value="myvalue">
    <input id="somethingelse" value="SE">
    <input id="ANum" type="number" value=99>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="OK">
</div>

<script> 
    $("#parentDivID input").val(''); 
</script>
```